# nested attributes ids arrays syntax problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So, there is a **working** part of code in rails 5. I'm making huge form with nested attributes on many levels. I've got an strong params list:

```
params.require(:lexeme).permit(
    :word, :homonym_number, :see_other_lexeme_id, :semantic_description, :afterword,
    variants_attributes: [ :word, :id, :_destroy, proofs_attributes: [ :word, :language_id, :meaning, :id, :_destroy, language_mode_ids: [] ] ]
  )
```

And when I tried to change order a little bit...

```
params.require(:lexeme).permit(
    :word, :homonym_number, :see_other_lexeme_id, :semantic_description, :afterword,
    variants_attributes: [ :word, :id, :_destroy, proofs_attributes: [ :word, :language_id, :meaning, :id, language_mode_ids: [], :_destroy ] ]
  )
```

I'm getting:

```
syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting =>
...guage_mode_ids: [], :_destroy ] ]
...                              ^):
```

So, rails masters, what is wrong with this simple syntax here, has always array parameters need to be placed as last? What if I have more arrays in params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the last `:_destroy` should be a `key => value` according to the syntax sugar lexical parsing.

If you want to retain the new order you need to make `language_mode_ids: []` a literal `Hash` like so:

```
params.require(:lexeme).permit(
  :word, :homonym_number, :see_other_lexeme_id, :semantic_description, :afterword,
  variants_attributes: [ :word, :id, :_destroy, 
    proofs_attributes: [ 
      :word, :language_id, :meaning, :id, {language_mode_ids: []}, :_destroy 
    ] 
  ]
)
```

Ruby is trying to help you by allowing you to specify `language_mode_ids: []` but it will require all the arguments on the right hand side of that to also represent a key value pair.

Since `:_destroy` is just a symbol the interpreter does not know what to do with this. That is why your first order worked and the new order does not.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. Sometimes syntax helpers could be confusing.